# If $Xp=0$ and $Yp=0$ then prove $YX^c=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let us consider two degenerate matrices $X$ and $Y$.  Suppose that there exists a vector $p$ such that $Xp=0$ and $Yp=0$. Then prove $YX^c=0$ where $X^c$ is cofactor matrix of $X$

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X$ has rank $<n-1$ then $X^c=0$ and we are done.

Otherwise, $p$ is (up to a scalar factor) the only vector in the kernel of $X$. Since $XX^c=0$, the columns of $X^c$ must be multiples of $p$. Thus each column of $YX^c$ is a multiple of $Yp=0$, thus is $0$, so $YX^c=0$.